# How to add border inner side of image using CSS

Tags: html, css, image, border

I want to display one inner line on all product image like following image.[image]

My HTML code like this:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="picture">
        <img id="main-product-img-43" src="//images/thumbs/0000072_25-virtual-gift-card_550.jpeg">
    </div>
</div>
```

How it can be possible using css/js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That one's quite simple. Put the image in a container, and give it an after. Give that after a absolute position and a border.

See the example:

```css
.gallery {
  height: 300px; /* change/remove as required */
  width: 400px; /* change/remove as required */
  border-radius: 10px; /* change/remove as required */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.picture:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  border: 2px solid pink;
  border-radius: 10px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="picture">
            <img id="main-product-img-43" itemprop="image" title="Picture of $25 Virtual Gift Card" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300" alt="Picture of $25 Virtual Gift Card">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

CSS:

```
img{
  outline: 1px solid white;
  outline-offset: -4px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="picture">
            <img id="main-product-img-43" itemprop="image" title="Picture of $25 Virtual Gift Card" src="//images/thumbs/0000072_25-virtual-gift-card_550.jpeg" alt="Picture of $25 Virtual Gift Card">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you use this, then keep in mind that IE doesn't support this property

Answer (score 2):

```css
#div {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  border: 1px solid magenta;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">

</div>
<!-- Replace the div with your image -->
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.gallery {
  border: solid 1px #DADADA;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}
.picture {
  border: solid 1px #FF69B4;
  height: 180px;
  width: 380px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="picture">
    //Image code
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's it, inner curved border inside the image.

```css
.picture {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;  
}
.picture:before {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid red;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.picture img{
  vertical-align : middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="picture">
            <img id="main-product-img-43" itemprop="image" title="Picture of $25 Virtual Gift Card" src="https://placehold.it/200x100" alt="Picture of $25 Virtual Gift Card">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: He wants the border to be inside the image

Comment: @Bálint. True. Updated.

Answer (score -1):

Use `pseudo-element` selector.

```
img {
 position: relative:
}
img:before { // this case i use :before
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 2%;
  top: 2%;
  width:98%;
  height: 98%;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}
```